# How can I disable mouseover function h tag area and png icon

Tags: mouseover

Hi guys I have a problem. I want show just normal my text on the image. When I do mouseover should be change image opacity except my text and png icon, it's should be  seen normal (without opacity ).Like that.Thanks http://demo.digipieces.com/gusteau-html/menu-1.html

```css
.foodMenu {
 text-align: center;
 height: 210px;
 width: 280px;
 position: relative;
 }
 
.foodMenu:after {
 content:'\A';
 position:absolute;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 top:0; 
 left:0;
 width:100%; height:100%;
 }
 
.foodMenu:hover:after {
 opacity: 1;
 }
 
 
.foodMenu .menuTitle {
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 32px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: none;
 position: absolute; 
    bottom:30px; 
    left:0;
    right:0;
 transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s cubic-bezier(x1,y1,x2,y2);  
 text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
 opacity: 0;
 }
 
.foodMenu:hover .menuTitle {
 opacity: 1;   
 bottom: 70px;
 }

.foodMenu .curve {
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: none;
 position:absolute;
    bottom:70px; 
    left:120px;
    right:0;
 opacity:0;  
 transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;  
 }
 
.foodMenu:hover .curve {
 opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="col span-1-of-4 step_box">
  <div class="foodMenu js-wp-2">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-280-210-1.jpg" alt="our menu meal">
    <h3 style="color:#ffffff;" class="menuTitle">Meals</h3>
    <img src="img/curve.png" alt="curve" class="curve">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any idea guys ???